# Programmatically getting the Authorization header for AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to work out my mobile data usage & I noticed there are simple APIs to query on `https://secure.example.com/myaccountmgr/fapi/usage/data/...` but they carry an `Authorization: 0a60bd4e0blahlblahhash` in order to query them.

I copied the curl commands when logging in, but it does a fairly complex [redirection dance](http://s.natalian.org/2016-03-30/cookie-compute.txt) that I not sure how to get curl to compute since it's Javascript.

How do people do this? After further debugging I noticed that it later does a AJAX request via Angular to `https://secure.example.com/myaccountmgr/fapi/login/esso` where it returns a `utoken` which is used in the subsequent AJAX requests as the `Authorization` value. So what I am asking, is how do I view just this response once I log in, so I can grab the token?

Comment: In a lot of ways. For me the simplest way would be to imitate a user just logging into an account with a login and a password via PhantomJS, storing cookies, then go to usage page and scrape it.

Comment: I am not sure where the AJAX request is constructed. How do I debug the AJAX requests and see the headers?

Comment: via developer tools. In Chrome's you can also see initiator for a http request.

Comment: The initiator is just a angular function. I wonder if I can search all variables after logging in for a token. A see a JSON token which seems to make the Authorization header but I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: So you're determined to solve?automate this using `curl`?